# We are given 10 red and 15 green balls. we are asked to draw two balls successively. What is the probability that one ball is red and other is green.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

### My effort for this question was

Since I have to select two balls so my sample space will be = $25C2$
and the favourable case is: $10C1$ $15C1$ because I have $10$ red balls and $15$ green balls, so my probability is $\dfrac{10C1\space 15C1}{25C2}$.

---

but the answer is something like this :
since we have to select two balls so sample space would be: $25 \cdot 24$
and the favourable case is : $10C1\space 15C1 + 15C1\space 10C1$.

so the probability would become : $\dfrac{10C1 \space 15C1 + 15C1 \space 10C1}{25 \cdot 24}$.

Can anybody please guide why the answer is like this?

***  Thanks in Advance   ***

Comment: Nice! Your answer is correct! Can you elaborate on the confusion you are having?  When you plug in $10C1 = 10, 15C1=15$ you see that the probability is 0.5.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct and is equivalent to the given answer.

If we select the balls sequentially, the first ball can be selected in $25$ ways, which leaves $24$ ways to select the second ball since the first ball is not replaced.  There are two favorable cases:

1. A red ball is selected first, then a green ball is selected second:  There are $10$ ways to select the red ball and $15$ ways to select the green ball, so there are $10 \cdot 15$ such cases.
2. A green ball is selected first, then a red ball is selected second:  There are $15$ ways to select the green ball and $10$ ways to select the red ball, so there are $15 \cdot 10$ such cases.

In total, the number of favorable cases is $10 \cdot 15 + 15 \cdot 10$.  Thus, the probability that one red ball and one green ball are selected when two balls are selected successively from $10$ red and $15$ green balls is 
$$\frac{10 \cdot 15 + 15 \cdot 10}{25 \cdot 24} = \frac{2 \cdot 10 \cdot 15}{25 \cdot 24} = \frac{10 \cdot 15}{\frac{25 \cdot 24}{2}} = \frac{\binom{10}{1}\binom{15}{1}}{\binom{25}{2}}$$
The author(s) took order of selection into account, while you did not.

Answer (score 1):

There are $10\cdot 15$ combinations of one red ball and one green ball.  There are a total of $25$ choose $2$ pairs to pick from, and $150$ them are "successful".  $25$ choose $2$ is $300$.  Thus the probability of success is $\frac{150}{300}=\frac{1}{2}$.